# Book about a world where magic was enabled by nano tech

Tags: story-identification, books

The world was described as a fantasy setting with the usual warriors, mages and thieves present. The mages had the instinctive ability to control the world's remaining nanobots. Level of control was determined by the accidental placement of nanobots at birth. If a mage had a cluster of bots in the knee he or she had rudimentary control of magic, if they happened to have the cluster in the brain, one would have a much more fine grained control.

I distinctly remember one of the main characters being a female mage, who tried to be a lot more inept in control. Always gathering a lot of static electricity and showing a lot more effort than actually needed. There was a incident where the mage was surprised by an attack and forgot to do all of the static building, effort imitating preamble while defusing the situation.

Publication time or format of the book is regretfully unknown to me as it was consumed in Ebook format.

Comment: This is a nice start but can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you read this? Was it new at the time? Was this a full length novel or more of a short story? Can you remember any of the story lines? If you can remember any of this remember to [edit] it into the question!

Comment: Not quite fitting the description (unless it's badly remembered), but in the interests of serving people who might stumble on this question by a google search, Ventus by Karl Schroeder has 'magic' that is enabled by nanotech, mostly operating on its own agenda but with some humans having rudimentary control/contact (and the main character developing even more than most).

Comment: Any sufficiently-miniaturised technology is indistinguishable, to the naked eye, from magic.

Comment: I don't think it's the same book, but there was a Doctor Who novel, [The Sorcerer's Apprentice](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice_(novel)), which was based around the same idea. The villain was trying to obtain the "Helm of Merlin", which would allow him to control the entire world network of nanobots and shut the other wizards out.

Comment: This has elements that sound like 'The Ship Who Saved The Wolds' by Anne McCaffrey and Jody Lynn Nye but the nano bots are missing, and it's not really a fantasy setting, just mages who use technology to cast magic.

Comment: I remember reading the exact book that the op was referring to. I wish I remembered the name I've been looking for it. I remember the world's technology has long since failed and they live Ina. Sort of back in time kind if setting. The main character was a teacher at a school where a girl was murdered and they found these white things in her mouth. I also remember they traveled to a dam and saw electricity working through light bulbs... The mage referenced is a lady who wore all red if I remember right. The quest they go on was given to them by a "ghost" of the girl

Answer (score 4):

I believe [*Trapped* by James Alan Gardner](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/837276.Trapped) matches this description. It's unfortunately not mentioned in the blurb, but the special powers were definitely nanotech-based, although I don't recall whether they were referred to as psionics or magic.

Comment: It was referred to as magic.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot but could it be [*Prophet Without Honour*](http://archive.anarchy-online.com/wsp/anarchy/frontend.cgi?func=publish.show&template=content&func_id=2319&table=CONTENT) (*Anarchy Online* Book One)
(2001) by Ragnar Tørnquist or even the game it sets the world building up for [*Anarchy Online*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchy_Online) if you've somehow confused a book with a video game.

In the series there are nanomages, mages whose magic is enabled by nano technology. The book's story line mainly seems to follow the backstory of the developments of the nano tech (though I haven't read it to be sure).

> “Even better,” Roland said. “We have already begun treatment on five test subjects. Our eminent and reliable Dr. Miller and his handpicked team have worked closely with New Jersey to facilitate for realtime alteration of chromosomes, using the new series of nanobots working on a molecular scale.” He paused. “And we seem to be making excellent progress. The combination of Miller’s miraculous little machines and my research into the aging process and the human genome has paid off. We can alter nature, my friends, and we can do so with confidence in the expected results.” He spread his hands and smiled. “In a short few years, you will all find yourself decidedly…reinvigorated.”
>
> <sub>*Prophet Without Honour*, New York, March 30th 2017 AD</sub>

Later on in the story they discuss how the air contains what could be used as the basis for a natural nano bot and this seems to lead into the nanomages in the game.

> “Fact is, Min, after looking over the readings I did, I’ve come to realise that this planet’s already got a microscopic substance resembling nanobots in the air. That’s simply amazing, and it means there’s a good reason why Omni-Tek has chosen to colonise Rubi-Ka. If this power, whatever it is, can be harvested…”
>
> <sub>*Prophet Without Honour*, Rubi-Ka, 28702 AD</sub>

---

I found this through quite a wild chase so bear with me here, I initially Googled `Book world magic enabled by nano tech` which led me to the Wikipedia article [Nanotechnology in fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotechnology_in_fiction). From there I searched the page for `magic` which led me to the Wikiepdia page for [*Anarchy Online*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchy_Online). Reading how the nano technology works in the game made me think it was plausible but as you mentioned it was a book I Googled `anarchy online book` which led me to the book.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are thinking about [***Didn't I Say to Make My Abilities Average in the Next Life?!***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didn%27t_I_Say_to_Make_My_Abilities_Average_in_the_Next_Life%3F!)
(Japanese: 私、能力は平均値でって言ったよね!, Hepburn: Watashi, Nōryoku wa Heikinchi de tte Itta yo ne!), which is a Japanese light novel series written by FUNA and illustrated by Itsuki Akata. A manga adaptation by Neko Mint began serialization in 2016.

> Misato Kurihara, a genius girl who couldn't make any friends due to her exceptional abilities, is killed after being run over while protecting a young girl. Offered the chance to be reborn into a fantasy world, Misato asks that she simply be reincarnated with average abilities. Reborn as the noble Adele von Ascham, she soon discovers that "average" in this new world takes into account the power of the absolute strongest and the absolute weakest magical creatures, resulting in her physical and magical abilities being 6,800 times stronger than that of a typical human, which is half of that of the strongest ancient dragon (the strongest of all the magical creatures). Attending Hunter's Prep School alongside her classmates Mavis, Reina, and Pauline, Adele tries her best to live her life as normally as possible, which does not prove to be an easy feat.

....

> **Nano** (ナノ, Nano)
> Voiced by: Wataru Hatano (anime)[7] (Japanese); Steve Staley (English)
> A mysterious creature that only shows itself to Adele. It watches over the nanomachines that make up people's magic in the other world, the remnants of a vastly advanced, now lost civilization. In the manga, it appears as a tiny, sphere-bodied robot, while in the anime it looks like a young cat.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a book called ***[Nanotech Magician](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CW1BHS9W)*** (2024) by Francisco Britez that used to post on Royal Road. You can find it on Amazon nowadays. There’s two books so far but it seems like there will be more soon. You can actually read both of them for free if you just make an Amazon Unlimited account.

> William, a bionically enhanced super-soldier, was Earth's last hope against an enigmatic invading force. Engineered for greatness by brilliant scientists, including his own father, he was meant to mature his extraordinary powers in the vastness of space before returning as humanity's protector.
>
> However, destiny had a different journey in mind. A critical malfunction sent his spacecraft crashing onto the bewildering planet of Xerxes, a land teeming with mythical creatures beyond imagination. Here, William finds himself surrounded by an array of humanoid beasts - from dwarves and elves to goblins and ogres - as well as mythical animals like phoenixes and hippogriffs.
>
> Guided by an advanced AI system with a mind of its own, William begins an enthralling journey of self-discovery into this alien realm. Under the mentorship of Moj Dak, one of Xerxes' legendary wizard guardians, William unlocks his untapped magical talents and forges an unbreakable bond with the mystical world around him.
>
> Yet greater forces are at play. A cruel twist of destiny has made William the unwilling host to General Ja'aduk, a malevolent warlock hungry for power. With catastrophe looming, he must confront the warlocks that plot to bathe Xerxes in apocalyptic darkness and emerge as the magical realm's prophesied savior.
>
> In a land where ancient sorcery and futuristic technology collide, the fate of Xerxes' mythical inhabitants rests on William's shoulders. Will his bionic enhancements and blossoming magical mastery be enough to defeat the warlocks' wrath and cement his destined hero status across this bewildering, beastly planet?

Comment: Was it out in 2019, at least?